# Facebook api returning undefine for relationship status

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get my friend's relationship here, but i give all the right permissions and it still says me, undefined.. it doesn't extract the relationship status of a friend, nor the birthday.. here is my code:

```
function loadFriendsrel()
{
    //get array of friends
    FB.api('/me/friends?fields=name,first_name,gender,picture,relationship_status,birthday', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var divContainer=$('.facebook-friends');
                         var testdiv2 = document.getElementById("test2");

for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
    if(response.data[i].gender == 'female'){
         testdiv2.innerHTML += response.data[i].first_name + '<br/>' + response.data[i].relationship_status + '<br/>' + ' ' + '<img src="' + response.data[i].picture + '"/>'  + '<br /> <br/>';
    }
}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you get all permission, you wont get `relationship_status` of users who have blocked them by their privacy settings.

> **Privacy settings have a higher priority than facebook api's.**

So, in your loop, some friends may have blocked their `relationship_status` , so it gives `undefined` and breaks your loop.

Change your loop to something like this,

```
for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
    if(response.data[i].gender == 'female'){
    var relStatus = 'Relationship status not provided';

    // If relationship_status exists, only then take its value
    if('relationship_status' in response.data[i]){
        relStatus = response.data[i].relationship_status;  
    }
    testdiv2.innerHTML += response.data[i].first_name + '<br/>' + relStatus + '<br/>' + ' ' + '<img src="' + response.data[i].picture + '"/>'  + '<br /> <br/>';
 }   
}
```

You can apply similar logic to other fields too.

Comment: Hi jASHWANT :) thanks for replying.. i did what you told me but i get this message for all of my friends...

Relationship status not provided

Comment: Hey :) i see you're from india, there are so many indians here that answer question, indian people are really smart :)

i wish i could come one day to india , sorry, maybe i sounded weird :p

Comment: If you are really want to thank me, mark my question as answer :)
You're always welcome in India. Its a must visit for everyone :)

Comment: sure, your answer was correct, at least the way it was written, but it must be something that has to do with facebook that won't let me extract the relationship status of a user :)

about India.. you're totally right, sorry for bothering, but are there any good technology institues in india? like professional ones?

Comment: I think this is not the right place to talk anything other than questions/answer. You can email me at jashwantsingh[@]gmail[dot]com